# Cannot import spreadsheet into SharePoint. This feature requires a browser that supports ActiveX controls

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Error while trying to import a spreadsheet into **SharePoint 2013**.
`-> site contents > add an app > import spreadsheet`. Error exists on both *Chrome* and *IE11*.

[image]

Have tried lowered the security and activated all ActiveX components but problem still persists.

Comment: are you using IE 11 or edge?

Comment: IE11 32-bit as mentioned. Operating in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev mode **(F12)** > Change document mode from **Edge** to **10**. 
IE will *reload* and import should *work*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable the **SharePoint SpreadSheet Launcher** in the IE.

IE-> Manage add-ons > Clcik on All Add-ons > then click to **SharePoint SpreadSheet Launcher** and click on Enable. Close the window then browser and try again.[image]

Some time you need to restart the PC.

Also try to Open the Browser in Compatibility Mode and then test it.

Comment: The add-on SharePoint Spreadsheet Launcher is enabled by default.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the reply! Error still persists. Compatibility Mode component is completely disabled with no options to enable. FYI, I currently do not have administrator privileges, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Open a Preview of your site from Sharepoint designer]

This way you will make sure that designer is "hooked" to the browser.
Then navigate on the browser ( **Make sure its IE 9 or 10**) to

1. Site content
2. Add app
3. Import from Excel

It should work now

Comment: Is the problem fixed? What version of Office are you using? We just updated to 2016 and it broke this functionality. Still waiting for Msft to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is introducing a feature to create a list from an Excel spreadsheet that's been uploaded to a SharePoint site. Not available in the version I'm using at the moment.

A work-around is to upload the spreadsheet into MS Access (if you have it), and publish to SharePoint from there.