# SPO 2013: import spreadsheet app throws "browser requires activex" error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, excel, import

Same issue as this [Cannot import spreadsheet into SharePoint. This feature requires a browser that supports ActiveX controls](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176061/cannot-import-spreadsheet-into-sharepoint-this-feature-requires-a-browser-that) but answers don't work.

When I click "import" I get:
"Cannot import spreadsheet into SharePoint. This feature requires a browser that supports ActiveX controls"
ActiveX is obviously enabled in IE11.SP sites are all in trusted lists.

This worked fine in retail Office 2010 but recent update to 2016 via Office 365 has broken it. Nothing else has changed in our environment so this is a Msft bug which they don't seem to know how to resolve.

IE11 32bit on Windows 7 Enterprise 
Office 2016 is 32bit.

Using a machine with Office 2013 and IE10, the import dialog opens but once the cell range is selected, I get:
"An unexpected error has occurred."

Comment: Try adding the site to the compatibility view in the IE - browser settings. Let me know if still doesnt solve your problem

Comment: I tried it on IE11 and IE10 and in compatibility view on both (so IE9). Also tried the dev tools emulation to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Use IE 32 bit version. 
Install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Restart the machine, clear the cache, check the browser settings of the active x controls are enabled and access the site.

Comment: I mentioned I'm using IE 32 bit. All the above tried to no effect.